# Как вложить один div в другой что бы значения шли по порядку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть [такой код.](https://jsfiddle.net/zgsbfw2j/136/)
В нем получаю ответ в виде xml в двух типах "комментарий" и "дата". Как мне дату вложить в комментарий, к примеру сверху? что бы шло по порядку. 1 коммент-1 дата и т.д.

```
.res{ border: 4px double black; 
background: #fc3; 
padding: 10px; 
width: 500px;
height: 100%;word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [промисы (Promise)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
То есть сразу после первого запроса для сообщений сделать второй на получение дат.

Вот решение: https://jsfiddle.net/zgsbfw2j/138/

Но еще лучше будет использовать [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/zgsbfw2j/139/

В таком случае второй промис стартует с первым не дожидаясь первого.

```js
var xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><digiseller.request><seller><id>793594</id></seller><product><id>2478332</id></product><reviews><type>all</type></reviews><pages><num></num><rows>33</rows></pages></digiseller.request>';

var requestMessages = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://shop.digiseller.ru/xml/shop_reviews.asp",
  data: xmlData
})
var requestDates = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://shop.digiseller.ru/xml/shop_reviews.asp",
  data: xmlData,
});

Promise.all([requestMessages, requestDates]).then(([messagesData, datesData]) => { 
 const results = document.querySelector('.results')
 const messages = [...messagesData.querySelectorAll("info")]
 const dates = [...datesData.querySelectorAll("date")]
  
  for (let index in messages)
    results.innerHTML += 
      `<div class="dat">${dates[index].firstChild.nodeValue}</div>` +
      `<div class="res">${messages[index].firstChild.nodeValue}</div>`
})
```

```css
.res{
  border: 4px double black; 
  background: #fc3; 
  padding: 10px; 
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results"></div>
```